# uploading a file to azure devops

Tags: angular, visual-studio, azure-devops, version-control

I have a project on DevOps let's say it's called 'Test' and I downloaded it as a zip to my local machine. I edited the code and now I want to upload the same file to the same directory in DevOps, will it update the already existing 'Test' folder ?

Or is there any way I can setup a 'source control' with change tracking ? Every article on google is saying to clone with the url, but the button or url is not present in the directory on DevOps.

I'm working on the Angular project, and it's not visible in Visual Studio.

Comment: If you don't see the button to clone your repo your repo propably isn't git but TFVC. You'll need VisualStudios "Source Control Explorer" to map that repo to a local directory, then you can edit your code there and "check in" your edited code

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Please let me if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload the same files to the same directory. It will update the files with the same filename in Devops.

Azure Repos provides two types of version control:

- [Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/?view=azure-devops): distributed version control.
- [Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/?view=azure-devops): centralized version control

From you what described in above question. You probably are using Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) in Azure Repos.

Please check document [Develop and share your code in TFVC using Visual Studio](http://Develop%20and%20share%20your%20code%20in%20TFVC%20using%20Visual%20Studio)

You can learn all you need to know in the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/?view=azure-devops) about Azure repos